# Is there a way to control my hard-disk rotation speed?

Tags: hard-drive

Can I control my hard disk rotation speed? IE adjust the RPM as and when I want. Google failed me in this.

At hardware level, the data stored which controls the hard-drive rotation speed can be accessed by the user?

Comment: Sorry, this site is for programming. Try your luck on http://superuser.com. Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/376939/how-do-i-get-my-disks-to-spin-down-after-one-hour) will already help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the actual RPM is not possible

http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/heads/op_Height.htm

In this article it says

"Modern drive heads float over the surface of the disk and do all of their work without ever physically touching the platters they are magnetizing. The amount of space between the heads and the platters is called the floating height or flying height. It is also sometimes called the head gap, and some hard disk manufacturers refer to the heads as riding on an "air bearing". The read/write head assemblies are spring-loaded--using the spring steel of the head arms--which causes the sliders to press against the platters when the disk is stationary. (This is done to ensure that the heads don't drift away from the platters; maintaining an exact floating height is essential for correct operation.) When the disk spins up to operating speed, the high speed causes air to flow under the sliders and lift them off the surface of the disk--the same principle of lift that operates on aircraft wings and enables them to fly."

And then another excerpt from this article

"The distance from the platters to the heads is a specific design parameter that is tightly controlled by the engineers that create the drive. By adjusting the strength of the springs to match the other drive parameters (such as the speed the disks are spinning and the size and shape of the heads) the float height can be precisely maintained."

I think it would be safe to assume that changing the speed of rotation of the platter, would also affect the amount of lift created and would either cause the heads to float to high, to the point where it could not read from the disk, or too low and could cause a head crash

Here's a link to the description of a head crash

http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/heads/op_Height.htm

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at hdparm util if you are using linux system. Unfotunately, it isn't allow you change hdd RPM but it allow you change some low-level performance options. Be care, some options can be dangerous.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm